# General form of function given that it is differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose a function satisfies the relation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

How can I show that the more general form of $f(x)$ is $f(x)=kx$ where $k$ is a constant given that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: First show $f(0)=0$. Now if $y\ne0$ you have $(f(x+y)-f(x))/y = (f(y)-f(0))/y$. Let $y$ tend to $0$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ is constant: since $f(0)=0$,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)+f(h)-f(x)-f(0)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)
$$